# Normalisation- check whether the following tables are in BCNF

Tags: mysql

I am making a project in MYSQL and have chosen the following tables:

```
Departments(DepartmentID, Department)
Primary Key = DepartmentID

Aisles(Aisle_Id,Aisle)
Primary Key = Aisle_Id

Products(product_Id, Product_Name, aisle_id, department_id)
Primary key=product_Id
foreign key= aisle_id, department_id

orders(order_id, user_id, eval_set, order_dow, order_hour_of_day)
primary key= order_id

order_products(order_id, product_id, add_to_cart, reordered)
foreign key= order_id, product_id
```

Just want to check that they are normalised and the design for my analysis looks good
what do you guys think?

Comment: What is eval set?

Comment: And is dow and hour of day really more sensible than a timestamp?

Comment: Primary key for order_products consists of the combination of order_id and product_id?

Comment: Check if an aisle actually does not belong to a department (and/or a department has specific aisles and others not). And also check if a product can really only be at a single place.

Comment: Also, order/shop systems are notorious for duplicating data (so they might not be the best topic to get a good bcnf vibe). If I order product a for price b, and you change that price in `products`, my order (my expressed intention to buy product a for price b) does not/should not change by you changing the price in the backend. You can inform me that the price changed, and I can accept or cancel the new conditions, but until then, the order needs to have/know about the old price. That's why you will oftentimes just copy such data when you add a product to an order. Similar for invoices, ...